# Remove button and assign on click

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on coding javascript and I'm kind of a noob here. This is my code:

```html
<button onclick="test()">Click Me!</button>
<script>
  function test()
  {
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var name = document.createTextNode("Button");
    btn.appendChild(name);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.onclick = ex();
  }

  ex()
  {

  }
</script>
```

I want to do two things, and I can't seem to find a solution. I want to:

1. use the function "ex" to remove the button that says "Click Me!"
2. assign btn.onclick to the button I just created.

Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT:** Although all you guys are trying to help me, I'm not sure you guys are quite understanding the question fully. So, expanding on the first request:
I want to use the function "ex" to delete the button "Click Me!" I want this button to be deleted from the page, and no longer visible.
Second:
I want the btn.click in the function "test" to only be assigned to the button created in the function "test." I've noticed that when you click "Click Me!" it runs the function "ex."

Answer (score 0):

### try this one

```
<script>
     function test() {
      var btn=document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
      btn.attributes[0].value="ex()";
      btn.innerText="second function"; 
     }
     function ex() {
      console.log("ex executer");
     }
     </script>
    <button onclick="test()">
     click me!
    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button onclick="test()">
Click Me!
</button>
<script>
function test(){
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
var name = document.createTextNode("Button")
btn.appendChild(name);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
btn.onclick = ex;//() remove. btn.onclick is a handler i.e. a function object,
// not the result your ex() returns. 
}
function ex(){//add function
    this.style.color = 'red'; // makes text of the button red
       // **ONLY if button IS clicked**
}
</script>
```